# jQuery: SlideUp on hover, stay open on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have a feature list for a product. I want to do the following:

1. On hover, slideToggle
2. If the user clicks on the element on hover, keep open until the user either hovers on another item or clicks on another item

Is this possible? So far I have the open/close on click working, but when I try to add in hover states it all goes awry. Here's a jsFiddle with the basic setup:
[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anneber/M5pes/)

HTML:

```
<p id="deadline-management" style="text-align: center;">Deadline Management »</p>
<p id="workflow-management" style="text-align: center;">Workflow Management »</p>
<div id="deadline-management-full" class="full-text">
     <h3 style="text-align: center;">DEADLINE MANAGEMENT</h3>

    <p class="p1">We know what deadlines mean and we know how bad life is when you miss one.</p>
    <div id="workflow-management-full" class="full-text">
         <h3 style="text-align: center;">WORKFLOW MANAGEMENT</h3>

        <p class="p1">We live in a world where there is always more to do than time to do it. Some things can wait, others can wait longer.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-text {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#deadline-management").click(function () {
    $("#deadline-management-full").slideToggle();
})
$("#workflow-management").click(function () {
    $("#workflow-management-full").slideToggle();
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a

```
.hover()
```

function; is that what you're looking for?

New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5pes/3/

If you want really specific behaviour on click and hover, you can use boolean variables to determine which events are fired at which time. Small example:

http://jsfiddle.net/M5pes/4/

The Deadline Management content won't slide on hover if it's already been clicked.

Comment: thank you! I had to change the code up a bit to make it work properly, but this set me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem, and I know; I didn't want to do the whole thing for you. I find that people learn better when nudged in the right direction rather than given the answer.  Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope **[this JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5pes/6/)** will give an answer to your question.

The code is a little bit complicated and probably needs some refactoring.

Here is the JS:

```
var hasClicked1
var hasClicked2

$("#deadline-management").hover(function () {
    hasClicked1 = false;
    $("#deadline-management-full").slideDown();
},

function () {

if (hasClicked1 || hasClicked2) {


} else {
           $("#deadline-management-full").slideUp('fast')          
           $("#workflow-management-full").slideUp('fast')  
}
});


$("#workflow-management").hover(function () {
    hasClicked2 = false;
    if( !hasClicked1) {
    $("#workflow-management-full").slideDown();
    }
}, function () {
    if (hasClicked2 || hasClicked1) {

    } else {
           $("#deadline-management-full").slideUp('fast')          
           $("#workflow-management-full").slideUp('fast')  
    }
})

$("#deadline-management").click(function () {
    hasClicked1 = true;
});


$("#workflow-management").click(function () {
    hasClicked2 = true;

});
```

If it answers your question, please mark the question as answered and ask me if you need to know anything in particular. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i think your idea is not very user friendly!
i changed it!

**CSS:**

```
*{
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
}
#head{
    background:#e4e4e4;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:0px;

}
#head:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#content{
    text-align:justify;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 2px 2px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <h3 id='head'>click here or mouseenter!</h3>
    <p id='content'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#content").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#content").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#head").click(function(){
        $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**» SEE IT ON [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/RQ9Zh/)**